# I'm getting a "AttributeError: module 'django.views' has no attribute 'my_form'" even though I have defined the function

Tags: python, django, forms, input

I'm very new to django and python and I was making a form to accept values from the user to store in the database and I keep running into a ModuleNoFoundError, even though I have written the module in views.py which I am importing. I am creating my own module and the html for the form and not using django form formats at all.

This is my views.py:

```
`from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from .models import My_Model
from .forms import MyForm

def my_form(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
    else:
      form = MyForm()
  return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

This is my urls.py:

```
`from django import urls
from django import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    urls(r'form', views.my_form , name='form')
]
`
```

This is the models.py:

```
`from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class My_Model(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    PRN = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    Phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    Email = models.EmailField()
    Department = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    S_Year = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name`
```

This is the forms.py:

```
`from django import forms
from .models import My_Model


class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    firstname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
        "placeholder": "firstname"
    }))
    lastname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
        "placeholder": "lastname"
    }))
    
    prn = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
        "placeholder": "prn"
    }))
    phone = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
        "placeholder": "Phone Number"
    }))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
        "placeholder": "Email"
    }))
    department = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
        "placeholder": "Department"
    }))
    S_Year = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
        "placeholder": "Year of Study"
    }))
    class Meta:
        model = My_Model
        fields = [
            'firstname', 'lastname','prn', 'phone', 'email', 'department', 'S_Year'
        ]
`
```

```
I keep getting this error:
```

```
`Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jyoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\jyoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jyoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jyoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 133, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\jyoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 485, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jyoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jyoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jyoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jyoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jyoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jyoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jyoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jyoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jyoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\jyoth\OneDrive\Documents\sneha proj\GDP\Pinnacle\pinnacle_project\pinnacle_project\urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    urls(r'form', views.my_form , name='form')
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'django.views' has no attribute 'my_form'`
```

Please help me resolve this.

I tried different solutions like adding the path to the views and urls directly, tried importing the function from the views file directly but they still show me error like:

```
`from .views import my_form
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pinnacle_project.views'`
```

or

```
`urls(r'form', views.my_form , name='form')
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     AttributeError: module 'django.views' has no attribute 'my_form'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the wrong module, you are importing it from `django`, so not your own. You can use:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from app_name.views import my_form

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('form', my_form, name='form'),
]
```

Where *`app_name`* is the name of the app where you have a `views.py` where you defined that view.

---

> **Note**: URLs normally have a *trailing slash* (i.e. `form/` instead of `form`). In fact, by default the [**`APPEND_SLASH`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#append-slash), which is by default set to `True`, will first try to match the path, and if no match is found, and the requested path has no slash, it will retry with an appended slash.